# What is the network connection speed between two containers communicating via a virtual bridge running on the same host?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, docker, lxc

Does a virtual bridge (added to /etc/network/interfaces) limit the transfer speed of data from the memory of one lxc/docker container to another?

For example does the memory throughput drop to that of 1G/10G Ethernet or is there no significant difference? That is would the throughput between two processes running on the same machine be almost identical to the two processes running on individual lxc containers on the same host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual interfaces do not artificially limit throughput to a particular data rate, like a physical interface would. However, they do incur software overhead, so you should expect transfer rates to be lower compared to simpler inter-process communication mechanisms, unless the bottleneck is some other factor.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. How significant would you estimate the software overhead to be? Could it be quantified using dd or some other bash method?

Comment: `dd` is pretty much useless for any kind of benchmarking.  if you want to do network benchmarks, see http://serverfault.com/questions/12484/what-program-can-i-use-to-benchmark-network-traffic

Comment: Personally, I like using `pv` and `nc` for simple, single-stream TCP performance tests. Something like `nc -l -p 12345 | pv >/dev/null` at one end and `nc ip.address.of.listener 12345 </dev/zero` at the other. You can try it on localhost/127.0.0.1 and then across containers and see how it differs. However, this isn't representative of all workloads, so take the results with a grain of sand. I did a quick test and I get 1.6GiB/s on localhost and 1.3GiB/s over a veth interface pair across network namespaces. Dedicated tools like `iperf` will be more flexible/accurate.